# How To Send String Value To Back end in an Angular get request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am expecting a get in net core with the stock name appended in the url. Here is the code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StockController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly Random generator = new Random();

    // GET api/stock/aapl
    [HttpGet("{r}")]
    public ActionResult<float[]> Get(
        string r,
```

I am not sure about the format in Angular get. This is what I have:

```
  getStock(name: string) {
// url should be api/stock/aapl
console.log("this.http.get<Cagr[]>(this.apiURL + '/api/stock' + {name});", this.http.get<Cagr[]>(this.apiURL + '/api/stock' + {name}))

return this.http.get<Cagr[]>(this.apiURL + '/api/stock' + {name});
}
```

Both the backend and frontend compile. The console.log statement sends this to the console , the format is not accurate:

```
console.log("this.http.get<Cagr[]>(this.apiURL + '/api/stock' + {name});", this.http.get<Cagr[]>(this.apiURL + '/api/stock' + {name}))
```

What format should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a slash. And your code will be more readable if you use placeholder instead of inline concatenation

```
const url = `${this.apiURL}/api/stock/${name}`;
return this.http.get<Cagr[]>(url);
```